# Neo4j - Issue with self-closing tags using Cypher

Tags: xml, neo4j, cypher

Good morning,

I am new to neo4j and I've working on a project that uses neo4j to process our XML data.

Our record looks like:

```
<iati-activity last-updated-datetime="2013-10-31T00:00:00-05:00" default-currency="CAD" hierarchy="1">
<iati-identifier>CA-3-A018823001</iati-identifier>
<activity-status code="4"/>
<reporting-org ref="CA-3" type="10"/>
<title xml:lang="en">National Water Quality and Availability Management </title>   
<description xml:lang="en">Results as of the project’s conclusion on May 1, 2010:  The project ... </description>
</iati-activity>
```

The following query

```
START  activity = node:entities(type="iati-activity") 
MATCH status-[?:`activity-status`]-activity-[:`reporting-org`]-org,
     activity-[?:title]-title,
     activity-[?:description]-description,
     activity-[?:`iati-identifier`]-id WHERE  HAS(org.ref) RETURN COALESCE(activity.title?, title.title) AS title
```

gave the following error:
The property 'reporting-org' does not exist on Node

However, changing the tag to the following works:

```
<reporting-org ref="CA-3" type="10">Foreign Affairs, Trade and
 Development Canada</reporting-org>
```

How to make this work with Cypher? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you executing the query when you get the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I executed the query from our Scala application. However, this seems to be environment independent because it seems that Neo4j doesn't like the fact of self-closing tags.

Comment: What I don't understand is how you query XML with Cypher. To use Cypher I assume you recreate your XML as a Neo4j db, and if you have problems with self containing XML tags the problem ought to be there not with the Cypher query. Is your XML possibly GraphML that you import with Neo4j shell tools, or do you have custom code wrapping XML or parsing it into a Neo4j db? Since `reporting-org` is not referenced as a node property in your query, it looks like the error couldn't be from Cypher at all (except if the error message is wonky). Do you have a stack trace to go with the error?

Comment: Thanks jjaderberg, yes, as you said, the problem has nothing to do with the Cypher query. It is related to the way our Neo4j records are created in the Graphic database. org.`reporting-org` is not available because `reporting-org` is created as the an attribute of the element "reporting-org", the same name caused the confusion.